# Payment processor for micro payments with EU Vat handling

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, mobile-application, payment-processing

At the moment I am using PayPal IPN to process micro payments (in the range of 1 EUR to 7 EUR) for mobile applications with a local hosted website store. The amount generated with these out-of-app-store sales in not very high but it is a service for my customers. Starting with January 1st 2015 a new law forces VAT calculation and payment based on each local European countries VAT rate.

Now I am looking for a payment processor who handles VAT charging. I already checked the Digitalriver products, and Fastspring, but both have minimum transaction fees which eat up much of the sales price.

Are there other payment processors with VAT handling which are more suitable for micro payments?

Regards,

Comment: Take a look at Taxamo. I has help me comply with the new law.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have implemented my own solution which summarizes all countries for quarterly submission.

All payment processors I found were too expensive for my few sales and micro payments.

Answer (score 1):

In case it is helpful to you or someone else, here is some PHP code which you could use to calculate the EU member state VAT rate for a visitor based on their IP address

Obviously, use at your own risk.  The VAT rates are correct at time of posting, but may change in the future.  The legislation requires two pieces of evidence for the correct country in the case of dispute.  You could use the code below as one piece of evidence, but you might need another piece.

```
function getIPAddress()
{
    $ret = "";
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
        $ret = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
        $ret = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else
        $ret = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    return $ret;
}

function getVatRateFromIpCountryCode()
{
    // Work out IP address and country code
    $remote_addr = getIPAddress();
    $xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.geoplugin.net/xml.gp?ip=".$remote_addr); // don't do more than 120 lookups in a minute or you'll get blacklisted for an hour
    $countryCode = $xml->geoplugin_countryCode;
    //$countryCode = "LU";  // test force contryCode

    // see http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/resources/documents/taxation/vat/how_vat_works/rates/vat_rates_en.pdf for current EU VAT rates
    $vat_percentage = 0;
    switch ( $countryCode )
    {
    case "EU":      $vat_percentage = 20;   break;  // unknown EU country
    case "BE":      $vat_percentage = 21;   break;  // Belgium
    case "BG":      $vat_percentage = 20;   break;  // Bulgaria
    case "CZ":      $vat_percentage = 21;   break;  // Czech Republic
    case "DK":      $vat_percentage = 25;   break;  // Denmark
    case "DE":      $vat_percentage = 19;   break;  // Germany
    case "EE":      $vat_percentage = 20;   break;  // Estonia
    case "EL":
    case "GR":      $vat_percentage = 23;   break;  // Greece
    case "ES":      $vat_percentage = 21;   break;  // Spain
    case "FR":      $vat_percentage = 20;   break;  // France
    case "HR":      $vat_percentage = 25;   break;  // Croatia
    case "IE":      $vat_percentage = 23;   break;  // Ireland
    case "IT":      $vat_percentage = 22;   break;  // Italy
    case "CY":      $vat_percentage = 19;   break;  // Cyprus
    case "LV":      $vat_percentage = 21;   break;  // Latvia
    case "LT":      $vat_percentage = 21;   break;  // Lithuania
    case "LU":      $vat_percentage = 15;   break;  // Luxembourg
    case "HU":      $vat_percentage = 27;   break;  // Hungary
    case "MT":      $vat_percentage = 18;   break;  // Malta
    case "NL":      $vat_percentage = 21;   break;  // Netherlands
    case "AT":      $vat_percentage = 20;   break;  // Austria
    case "PL":      $vat_percentage = 23;   break;  // Poland
    case "PT":      $vat_percentage = 23;   break;  // Portugal
    case "RO":      $vat_percentage = 24;   break;  // Romania
    case "SI":      $vat_percentage = 22;   break;  // Solvenia
    case "SK":      $vat_percentage = 20;   break;  // Slovakia
    case "FI":      $vat_percentage = 24;   break;  // Finland
    case "SE":      $vat_percentage = 25;   break;  // Sweden
    case "UK":
    case "GB":      $vat_percentage = 20;   break;  // United Kingdom
    default:        break;
    }
    //echo "countryCode = '$countryCode', vat_percentage = $vat_percentage<BR>";    // debugging
    return $vat_percentage/100;
}
```